# Marketing Cloud SQL converting datetime to date field for dateadd function

Tags: sql, sql-server, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm using SQL server in Marketing Cloud to write a data extension that will allow me to report on Salesforce Opportunities that have a closedate within 90 days of an email's open date.

I selected all the fields I need to be able to run the reporting in Excel, and joined my datasets together.

I have a where clause in the query:

```
and o.closedate < dateadd(day, 91, 'e.et4ae5__DateOpened__c')
```

The SQL validates, but I get error:

> Could not convert date and/or time from string data type.

closedate is a date field format yyyy-mm-dd, where dateopened is a datetime field. Do I need to convert the datetime to a date field before using it in the dateadd function?

I tried adding to the select statement: `convert('e.et4ae5__DateOpened__c', getdate(), 23)` and I'm getting error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'e.et4ae5__DateOpened__c'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (Edit) The error says what the problem is. SQL Server can't convert the literal *string* *"et4ae5__DateOpened__c"* into a date.  Column names should not be enclosed in single quotes. If it contains special characters, use brackets `[` and `]`

Answer (score 0):

`'e.et4ae5__DateOpened__c'` is a string and SQL Server (just like me) is not understanding what this could mean as date.

It might be a column identifier, though. `e` being the alias and `et4ae5__DateOpened__c` being the column name.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I changed the select statement to:

```
convert(date, [et4ae5__DateOpened__c], 23) as [et4ae5__DateOpened__c]
```

and the where clause to:

```
o.closedate < dateadd(day, 91, [et4ae5__DateOpened__c])
```